# Git Merge Branches Conflict Marker Resolution

Tags: git, merge

I am merging a branch called `temp-fix` into the `master` branch. At the moment, I am working on resolving merge conflicts. I would like to accept all changes that came from the `temp-fix`.

How could I do it given the conflict markers below?
That is, which code should I delete and which leave in place for this to work as planned?

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
/**
 * fetch  count(order_no) need to disable/grey out the departmental membership.
 */
function personify_count_departmental_membership($masterid) {
  $pdb = new PersonifyDB();
  $sql = "select count(order_no)
                  from ORDER_DETAIL (nolock)
                  where subsystem = 'MBR'
                  and ship_master_customer_id = '$masterid'
                  and cycle_begin_date <= getdate() and grace_date >= getdate()
                  and line_status_code in ('A','P')
                  and parent_product = '';

  $results = $pdb->p_query($sql);
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
/**
 * fetch  count(order_no) need to disable/grey out the departmental membership.
 */
function personify_count_departmental_membership($masterid) {
  $pdb = new PersonifyDB();
  $sql = "select count(order_no)
                  from ORDER_DETAIL (nolock)
                  where subsystem = 'MBR'
                  and ship_master_customer_id = '$masterid'
                  and cycle_begin_date <= getdate() and grace_date >= getdate()
                  and line_status_code in ('A','P')
                  and parent_product = '';
>>>>>>> temp-fix

<<<<<<< HEAD
  return $results;
}
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
  $results = $pdb->p_query($sql);

  return $results;
}
>>>>>>> temp-fix
```

Answer (score 2):

Accept **theirs** while merging. Here, `temp-fix` is *theirs* and `master` is *ours*. You can use theirs/ours flag while merging.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard HEAD

$ git pull origin temp-fix -s recursive -X theirs # accept 'temp-fix' branch changes if conflict occurs
Or,
$ git pull origin temp-fix
$ git checkout --theirs -- .                      # checkout the files to 'temp-fix' changes
```

Comment: If already started merging then, try `git checkout --theirs -- .`

Comment: `checkout --theirs` is VERY DIFFERENT from `-X theirs`!

Answer (score 2):

*Since you are merging the **temp-fix** branch into the **master** branch and want to keep all changes of temp-fix, delete the code between **<<<<<<< HEAD** and **=======***

Delete the following piece of code:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
/**
 * fetch  count(order_no) need to disable/grey out the departmental 
membership.
*/
function personify_count_departmental_membership($masterid) {
  $pdb = new PersonifyDB();
  $sql = "select count(order_no)
              from ORDER_DETAIL (nolock)
              where subsystem = 'MBR'
              and ship_master_customer_id = '$masterid'
              and cycle_begin_date <= getdate() and grace_date >= getdate()
              and line_status_code in ('A','P')
              and parent_product = '';

  $results = $pdb->p_query($sql);
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======



<<<<<<< HEAD
  return $results;
}
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======

>>>>>>> temp-fix
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Resolving different changes

When you run `git merge`, you are—at least in the most general case<sup>1</sup>—telling Git to do its best to combine two *different* sets of changes.  That is, both you, Mad Physicist, and someone else—I'll call him Joe—*started* from the same code, but you *both* made changes since then.

What Git does is, in essence, to run two `git diff`s:

1. Figure out which version you both started from.  Let's say that was version `ba5eba5`.
2. Figure out what version *you* have now.  Let's say that's `HEAD`, because it is. :-)  HEAD translates to some incomprehensible hash ID, but we can just say "HEAD".
3. Figure out what version *Joe* has now.  That's `temp-fix`, which, like `HEAD`, turns into some incomprehensible hash ID, but again we can just say `temp-fix`.
4. Run `git diff ba5eba5 HEAD`: that's what *you* changed.
5. Run `git diff ba5eba5 temp-fix`: that's what *Joe* changed.
6. Try to *combine* the changes.

Where they *don't* overlap—e.g., if you deleted five lines starting at line 42, and Joe added three lines starting at line 127—Git just assumes that the right answer is to take *both* changes: delete those same five lines, and add those same three lines, to the base version.

Where they *do* overlap, you get a "merge conflict".  Git writes *both* sets of changes into the file, with the markers.  If you have `merge.conflictStyle` set to `diff3`, Git writes what was in the original base file in as well, as the "merged common ancestors".  Setting this is a good idea, as it tells you what conflicted.

In this case, both you and Joe *added* code, without deleting anything at all.  The "merged common ancestors" section is therefore *empty*.

If you want to take Joe's version, simply delete *your* added code and the merged common ancestors part, and keep Joe's version (and then delete the conflict markers).  If you think your version is better, delete Joe's and keep yours.

---

<sup>1</sup>In many rather common cases, either you made changes and Joe didn't, or Joe made changes and you didn't.  In this case Git just takes your version, or Joe's version, and calls it good-and-done.  If the `ba5eba5` *common base itself* is the same as your HEAD version, or the same as Joe's temp-fix, everything gets very easy.  In one case (base = Joe, so you are ahead) there's nothing to merge, and in the other (base = you, but Joe is ahead) Git can do a so-called "fast forward" and just move right up to Joe's hash-ID.

---

#### Automating some or all of this

When you start the merge, you can supply `-s` or `-X` (or both) arguments.  The names Git uses for these are, in my opinion, not very good (too confusing): `-s` selects a *strategy*, and `-X` passes a *strategy option* to the selected strategy (which usually defaults to the right one anyway, so usually you just want `-X`).  I like to say that `X` stands for *eXtenteded option*, which is not a lot better, but at least avoids saying "strategy" yet again.

There is an `ours` *strategy*, which is not what you want, and there are both `ours` and `theirs` *extended* options, which are sometimes what you want.  So `-X theirs` makes sense: it means **if there is a conflict,** favor Joe's over mine.  Note the boldface part, though!  **If** there is a conflict.  If there is *no* conflict—if you deleted five lines near the top, and Joe did not touch those lines—Git **still takes both changes**.  Only in the event of a conflict does Git automatically favor Joe.

Once Git stops with a conflict in the file, you can examine either your version, or Joe's version, using the *same ours/theirs notation*:

```
git checkout --ours -- somefile.pl
```

or:

```
git checkout --theirs -- somefile.pl
```

(the `--` protects you if for some reason the file is named `-f.pl` for instance: it's just a good habit to get into but not required for this case).  But this means *extract the whole thing from HEAD or from Joe's commit*, which *removes* the other guy's changes.  If you deleted five lines, and they should stay deleted, but you `git checkout --theirs` to get Joe's version, those five lines are *back*.

Of course, if *all* the changes you made conflict with the ones Joe made, *then* extracting Joe's version will get you the same result that `-X theirs` would.  But that's a pretty big "if".

To reconstruct the merge conflict, you can:

```
git checkout -m -- somefile.pl
```

and then manually merge.  (But see the next section.)

Once you have the final version of the file ready, you must `git add` it to tell Git to copy the work-tree version into the index.  The index currently has *all three* (base, ours, theirs) versions, in the three extra slots, with the "resolved" slot for the file unoccupied.  Adding the resolved file fills in slot zero, where normal, resolved files go, and wipes out slots 1-3 where the unresolved files are kept.

#### Re-doing the merge of one specific file, with -X options

You can get Git to re-do the merge of *one specific file* without starting the whole merge over again with the appropriate extended option.  It's annoyingly difficult, though.  (This is one case where Mercurial has Git beat all hollow: what I'm about to show is all pre-packaged.)

If you extract *all three* versions of the file, you can now run `git merge-file` on them, getting the effect of `-X theirs`:

```
git checkout -- :1:somefile.pl
mv somefile.pl somefile.pl.base
git checkout --theirs somefile.pl
mv somefile.pl somefile.pl.theirs
git checkout --ours somefile.pl
git merge-file --theirs somefile.pl somefile.pl.base somefile.pl.theirs
```

To get the effect of `-X ours` (favor our change if conflicting), use `git merge-file --ours`.  Once that's done, remove the `.base` and `.theirs` versions of the file.

(As usual, once you have resolved the conflict, you must `git add` the file to copy it back into the index, at slot zero, to mark it as done.)

Comment: Thank you. This was both thorough and educational. Just to clarify, which section would have the common code? Is it this one? Between these lines? `||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
`

Comment: Since there was no code deleted, I think I may need to keep both changes. Does this mean I can simply delete the markers and commit the file?

Comment: Right, if you'd both deleted a few lines and replaced them with the new lines, that would be the "merged common ancestors" part. Whether both new sections of code "play well together" is a separate question entirely though. A classic example occurs where you fix a bug one way, and they fix it another way. Do both things and you get a new bug: something done twice, or it doesn't work at all, for instance. Pick either one and you're OK, unless *one* fix involved adding or deleting something elsewhere, and you pick the wrong one of the two...