# After a git pull there a lot of unrelated modifications in the staging area

Tags: git, merge

A colleague had been working in his local repository on `master` and after a couple of weeks, did a `git pull`.  In the meantime there was a bunch of activity on master including at least 10 merge commits (we have been using a merge workflow so far).

After the pull there were a handful of files that had conflicts.  But the unexpected thing was that there were hundreds of modifications in his staging area to files that he did not work on, and each of those modifications was reverting a change on `origin/master` that was made since the common ancestor commit.   For example:

### Changes since the common ancestor

His branch (`master`)

- A: add 3 lines
- B: delete 2 lines
- C: remove 1 line
- G1..G99: new files

`origin/master`

- C: add 2 lines
- D: delete 10 lines
- E: change 20 lines
- ...: many more files changed
- N1..N3: new files
- D1..D5: deleted files

### After `git pull`

Modifications in the staging area

- A: delete 3 lines
- B: add 2 lines
- G1..G99: new files
- All other changes from `origin/master` are gone.  N1-N3 are missing, D1-D5 are back.

In conflict

- C

I've replicated the problem to verify that he didn't do anything special besides a plain `git pull`.

Unfortunately he committed all of these changes and I ended up needing to revert that commit.  But I want to understand why this would happen so we can avoid it in the future.

I've read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462988/git-pull-brings-others-commits-into-my-staging-area-during-merge-conflict) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189867/after-a-git-merge-conflict-a-lot-of-files-i-didnt-touch-become-changes-to-be-c) questions, but none of them answer the question: Why would Git revert the changes from `master` when there were no changes in the corresponding files on his branch?   I understand why there would be modifications in the staging area when there are conflicts after a pull, but I don't understand why they would be effectively reverting the work on `origin/master` since the common ancestor.

Our approach to the problem right now is

- Use `git pull --rebase` instead of merging
- Check the status after a pull and don't commit
  if there are unexplainable modifications

Comment: One thing I should also mention - the `origin/master` side of the merge had a rats nest of branches because people have been mostly working on `master` using a merge workflow.  There were branches 7 levels deep at some points.  I can see how Git could get confused.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** (based on question-edit for more details): it seems possible that this is a case where rename detection has gone wrong, and possibly there's a criss-cross merge in the history as well, so that Git is forming a "virtual merge base".

To find out, first run:

```
git merge-base --all <hash1> <hash2>
```

on the two hash IDs that the two branch names `master` and `origin/master` pointed-to at the time the mis-merge happened.  We need this to test out both whether rename detection is a problem, and whether there are multiple merge bases.

If this prints *more than one* hash ID, you are getting the `recursive` strategy to merge the merge-bases, followed by using the resulting merge as a new merge base.  This can (in rare cases) produce very confusing results.  If so, switching to the `-s resolve` strategy may help.  This will pick one of the two merge bases and stick with it.  (But you have no control over *which* merge base is used.)  Note that setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` will also [sometimes show you the effect of a virtual merge base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31392513/1256452) (but only sometimes)

Next, whether or not there are multiple merge bases, we can check to see if rename detection is causing problems.  If so, there are two things that may help:

- The sledgehammer approach: disable rename detection entirely during merge (requires Git version 2.8 or higher): add `-X no-renames`, which matches the spelling for `git diff` (though there it's `--no-renames`).
- The finer-tune-able tack hammer: raise the limit for detection (the default is 50%): `-X rename-threshold=100` or `-X find-renames=100` requires an exact match instead of an approximate match.  The new spelling, `-X find-renames=<n>`, matches the spelling for the `git diff` option and is new in Git version 2.8, but the option itself is very old, having been around since version 1.7.4.  Note that other threshold values are allowed as well, although 100% exact match is quite notable.

To find out if Git is detecting renames, we need *the* merge base, which is a bit of a problem if there are multiple merge bases: we have to merge the merge bases first, to get a real merge commit that Git will use as the new merge base.  I'll just assume that this is *not* the case, since that process is a bit messy; so we'll go on to look at "the" merge base, using:

```
git diff --name-status --find-renames=50 --diff-filter=R <basehash> <hash1>
git diff --name-status --find-renames=50 --diff-filter=R <basehash> <hash2>
```

The `<hash1>` and `<hash2>` values are the same as before.  We tell Git to give us file names and statuses, and then print only the names of files whose status is `R` (renamed).  If Git *does* think some files are renamed, we will see their old and new names here.  How Git combines these during a merge is a bit tricky, but the presence alone of `R`-status files implies that Git will be doing this sort of thing.  If there are *no* files, then it's not rename-detection after all.

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40352403/1256452) for a detailed description of rename detection in `git diff`.  The merge code uses different command line options, some of which have changed relatively recently.  See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672618/1256452) to [Disable Git Rename Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6013261/1256452) as well.)

Original answer below.

---

In general, when merging, Git does not choose *either* "side".  Instead, it takes *both* sides.  Remember that there's a *third* side to this whole three-way merge thing: there's "your" side (HEAD), "their" side (what you're merging), and the *base*.  This forms a triangle:

```
                o    <-- HEAD
             ...
            o
         ...
...--o--B (base)
         ...
            o
             ...
                o   <-- theirs
```

and the merge brings them all together to make a shiny (we hope) diamond:

```
            o
           / \
          o   \
         /     \
...--o--B       o   result
         \     /
          o   /
           \ /
            o
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42839372/1256452) and [this more technical / detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104116/1256452).

Meanwhile, it turns out that at least some GUI interfaces present this fact to users.  They get scared by the idea that there are many changes to many files, when *they* changed only *one* file.  They instruct their GUI to undo all the other changes—which means *throw away the other users' work!*  They then commit this, and you have to revert *their* merge to get the other users' work back.

(Another source of "touch every file" is when users enable end-of-line conversions in their setups.  They take incoming code that uses LF-only or CRLF endings, and convert it to CRLF, or to LF-only, respectively.  Then they commit all these changes, which means they have altered every line of every file.)

Comment: I've added clarifications to my post.

Comment: Aha, I wonder if it's rename-detection-gone-wrong now.  I'll add that and another link...

Comment: It looks like there is one merge base: `git merge-base --all a6e112cec eeedb3cdb`
`76ef56fff60b2cbef3f8c787a8d15c522868a914`

Comment: `git diff --name-status --find-renames=50 --diff-filter=R 76ef56fff60b2cbef3f8c787a8d15c522868a914 a6e112cec` and `git diff --name-status --find-renames=50 --diff-filter=R 76ef56fff60b2cbef3f8c787a8d15c522868a914 eeedb3cdb` both return no output.   I also tried 25/75/90 values for `--find-renames`.

Comment: Well ... that's fascinating, it's an ordinary merge and there are no renames, and yet the merge goes terribly wrong. At this point I'm out of "off the top of my head" type ideas; I'd have to have a closer look at the repository itself (and any special configurations you might be using).

Comment: Ok - thanks for helping out!  I've learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: BTW it may be interesting to look at the output from both `git diff --name-status` results *without* the `--diff-filter=R`, to see what files *Git* thinks changed from base to each branch-tip.  Or even remove the `--name-status` part, to see the changes themselves.